While Converting DataTable to Json , datetime is getting with "\\/Date(1722796200000)\\/\" format
While Converting the DataTable to Json File, the field with DateTime is converting to a *\/Date(1722796200000)\/*? there is any solution to convert the method to a real datetime or  json datetime format "2024-08-05T00:00:00"
Structure of DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "TestJson";
dt.Columns.Add("No", typeof(short));
dt.Columns.Add("CDate", typeof(DateTime));


Datatable Format




No
Date




1
05/08/2024 00:00:00


2
06/08/2024 00:00:00



Code to add Data to DataTable 

dt.Rows.Add(1, Convert.ToDateTime(txtODate.Text));

Convertion process
string JsonData= DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(Dt);

public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);

}

The Result Am getting

[{"No":1,"CDate":"/Date(1722796200000)/"}]

While due to this , when saving to SQL Server it is showing

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"


using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System;
using System.Data;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);

        // Convert DataTable to JSON with custom date format
        string json = ConvertDataTableToJson(dt);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    public static string ConvertDataTableToJson(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        // Create settings with a enter code herecustom date format
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" // ISO 8601 format
        };

        // Serialize DataTable to JSON
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable, settings);
        return json;
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

This is the default behavior of JavaScriptSerializer according to the documentation.

Date object, represented in JSON as "/Date(number of ticks)/".

If you want the date to be serialized in ISO8601 format, you should use the Newtonsoft.Json library:
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);

Or using System.Text.Json library:
using System.Text.Json;

...

return JsonSerializer.Serialize(rows);


ok, thanks, but on saving in the DataBase this format is showing error with dateConvertion {"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"}

Looks like this is another question. It depends on how you are saving the data, using parameter used query/stored procedure? Are you providing the parameters with type according to the column?

Yes , date parameter is using.

By using the following syntax to solve the issue.  ( in the SQL side)
  Select DATEADD(SECOND, (CAST(SUBSTRING(CDate, CHARINDEX('(', CDate) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', CDate) - CHARINDEX('(', CDate) - 1) AS BIGINT)) / 1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')

